# Pointwise limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, alternative-proof

I am finding an alternative proof of the following theorem:

**Th.** Let $(X,\mathcal S)$ be a measurable space.Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of measurable functions from $X\to \mathbb R$.If $f=\lim f_n$ exists then $f$ is measurable.

I am looking for an easy and intuitive proof rather than the one I found in my textbook by Axler:

Let $a\in \mathbb R$.

It suffices to show that $f^{-1}(a,\infty)\in \mathcal S$.

Now,$f^{-1}(a,\infty)=\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap\limits_{k=m}^\infty f_k^{-1}(a+\frac{1}{j},\infty)$ and from here the claim follows.

But the problem with this proof is that it is not intuitive although it is a short one.Can someone give a different proof?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy No,it is correct.I can prove it.Let $x\in f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ then $f(x)>a$ so $f(x)>a+1/j$ for some $j\in \mathbb N$ .So there exists $m\in \mathbb N$ such that $f_n(x)>a+1/j$ for all $n\geq m$ So,$x\in \bigcap\limits_{n\geq m}f_n^{-1}(a+1/j)$ for some $j\in \mathbb N$

Comment: $x\in \bigcup\limits_{j\geq 1}\bigcup\limits_{m\geq 1}\bigcap\limits_{n\geq m}f_n^{-1}(a+1/j)$

Comment: For the other direction.Let $x\in \bigcup\limits_{j\geq 1}\bigcup\limits_{m\geq 1}\bigcap\limits_{n\geq m}f_n^{-1}(a+1/j)$.Then $\exists j,m$ such that $f_n(x)>a+1/j$ for all $n\geq m$ thus $f(x)\geq a+1/j>a$ by taking $n\to \infty$ .